# Wait to return until object has value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a method that gets called that looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)getClassNamesWithClassID: (NSNumber *) classID {
    NSLog(@"Gettting Name for classID: %@", classID);

    NSURLRequest *classIDRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dphs.edu20.org/api/get_classes_with_ids?api_key=%@&classIDs=%@", apiKey, classID]]];

    NSURLConnection *classIDConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:classIDRequest delegate:self];

    return className;
}
```

Below this, there are all of the delegate methods for the `NSURLConnection`. The variable `className` is set in the delegate's 1connectionDidFinishLoading1 method. However, it needs to be returned in the above `getClassNamesWithClassID` method. When I try to call the `getClassNamesWithClassID` method, the method always returns `nil`, presumably because the `NSURLConnection` takes some time to receive the data and then set it to the `className` variable but the return is happening before all of this occurs. How can I have the method "wait" until the `NSURLConnection` is complete until it returns `className`?

**EDIT**

Synchronous connection code:

```
- (NSString *)getClassNamesWithClassID: (NSNumber *) classID {


classDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NEOAPIData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Gettting Name for classID: %@", classID);

NSURLRequest *classIDRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dphs.edu20.org/api/get_classes_with_ids?api_key=%@&classIDs=%@", apiKey, classID]]];

NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:classIDRequest
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];
if (data)
{
    [NEOAPIData appendData:data];
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:NEOAPIData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",strData);
    classDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:NEOAPIData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    return @"Hello";
}

return @"Error";
}
```

Comment: Avoid naming methods with `get`. This usually implies that the caller must supply a buffer, e.g. `[NSArray getObjects:count:]` or `[NSString getCharacters:range:]`.

Comment: @dreamlax ok, noted for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't, and you shouldn't.

NSURLConnection (which is now deprecated BTW) is an async method. It returns immediately, before the network request has even been sent, much less data received.

What you need to do is refactor your getClassNamesWithClassID method to be a method that takes a completion block with the class name as a parameter to that block. Then write your code so that it saves the completion block to an instance variable and invokes it in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method. Then write the caller to pass in code that should be invoked once the class name is known.

Comment: Alright, how exactly would I go about doing this? Sorry I am new to Objective-C.

Comment: Basically what I have is a class that will fetch data from an API and then return the result of whatever that API gives back to whatever called the class in the first place. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That way won't work because network requests should be asynchronous. You need to refactor your design to either pass in completion blocks that get called once the data is available, or set up a delegate that gets notified when the data is available. Both approaches work, but the completion block approach is more modern and generally preferred these days.

Comment: Technically, you can. But agree, you shouldn't.

Comment: rmaddy, shh... I decided that mentioning that technicality was counter-productive. Let's not teach newbies how to freeze the UI with synchronous network methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need call NSURLConnection synchronous like following code

```
- (NSString *)getClassNamesWithClassID: (NSNumber *) classID {

    NSLog(@"Gettting Name for classID: %@", classID);

    NSURLRequest *classIDRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dphs.edu20.org/api/get_classes_with_ids?api_key=%@&classIDs=%@", apiKey, classID]]];

    // NSURLConnection *classIDConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:classIDRequest delegate:self];

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:classIDRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        // Parse data here
        return className;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Change the `if` statement to `if (data)`.

Comment: When I try to parse the data, the data is nil.

Comment: @woakley5 I need to explain what your request URL with full api_key and classIDs

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I hid the apiKey and classIDs variables from view because this is a public forum.

Comment: @woakley5 I don't know what exactly did you get. not use "if (data)", use if (error == nil). if get "error != nil" show log it here